# Ria Services Wizard with referenced Entity model problem?

Tags: entity-framework

Imagine this structure. A solution with the following projects

- /Backend (RIA Silverlight client)
- /Backend.Web (RIA Silverlight Host /
  Service)
- /Core (Utility includes)
- /Frontend.Web (Front line MVC app)

A entity framework model built in /Core should be able to be seen in Backend.Web IF there is a reference. Which there is. Now, when the Domain Service creation wizard shows up, it is happy to find the Entity model, but it will not enable the "Generate associated classes for metadata" option.

The only solution seems to be putting the Edmx file into /Backend.Web - but that seems ugly to me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It woudl appear that this scenario is better handled with a "RIAServicesLibrary" as mentioned by @brada in [his blog post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/28/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-11-the-new-class-library-project.aspx#9851730).